# Thread Count for Spring Async Method

Tags: spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot controller method. I access to a service class from it and it has a method which is annotated by `@Async`.

Since service is a singleton within Spring, does it unnecessary to assign more than one thread for my thread pool which just manages that async method? My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyApp-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: A singleton (service) can be used by multiple threads at the same time (e.g. in case multiple requests arrive at the same time), which implies your (singleton) service needs to be thread-safe. It also means that the async-method can be called by different threads at the same time, so in that case, you will need a thread-pool with several threads to handle the async-method calls concurrently.

Comment: That service class is only accessed by a controller method via REST. Does your comment still valid according to that? Can same users' concurrent requests or different users requests cause such a multi threaded access to that service class?

Comment: In a typical setup, yes. Easy enough to test also: just put a long `Thread.sleep` in the service method accessed by the controller method via REST and watch what happens when two users fire the same REST request at about the same time.